# How does YouTube determine what a view is?

Tags: youtube

I have heard from some people that a view counts when you watch the video for more than a minute and others have said 15 seconds.

How does YouTube determine what a view is?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the view count is updated automatically. According to YouTube, the platform keeps its actual method of tabulation under wraps to prevent people from finding ways to beat the system. So there is not any official saying 15 or 30 seconds...but in my opinion, views on YouTube videos must be at least 30 seconds and all YouTube views must be real human viewers not by bot driven or software, and it must be distributed over time.